# in_array が意図した通り動かない

Tags: php, array

.txtから取り出した文字「com」が配列の中に含まれているか調べたいのですが"$tld は許可されたTLDの中に含まれていません。"が出力されます。$tld = 'com';と書くと"$tld は許可されたTLDの中に含まれています。"と出力されるのですが、.txtから取り出した文字だと動かなくなります。$tldにはちゃんとcomが入っているのはechoで確認済みです。
わかる方何卒宜しくお願い致します。

```
// 定義されているTLD
$allowed_tlds = array('com', 'net');
$key = in_array($tld, $allowed_tlds);
// $TLDが許可されたTLDの中に含まれているかを確認
if ($key) {
    echo "$tld は許可されたTLDの中に含まれています。";
} else {
    echo "$tld は許可されたTLDの中に含まれていません。";
}
```

Comment: コードは一部だけを抜き出すのではなく、txtファイルから値を取り出す処理も含めて再現するコードを質問に記載してみてください。

Comment: `.txt` から取り出す部分の処理が判りませんが、ファイルから読み込んだ文字列ということだとすれば、改行コードが付いたままになっているのかもしれません。`$tld = trim($tld);` としてから `in_array(...)` を実行してみてください。

Comment: @metropolis 改行コードが付いたままでした。ありがとうございます。

Comment: もし解決した場合には、コメントのやり取りを元に個別の回答として投稿してみてください。